# Issue with installing Postgres on Vagrant VM using Chef: undefined method `ruby' for Config:Module

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, provisioning

That's how my `Vagrantfile` looks :

```
   config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"

     chef.json = {
        postgresql: {
            password: {
                postgres: 'password'
            }
        },
        database: {
            create: ['mydb']
        },
        'build-essential' => {
            compiletime: true
        }

     }
     chef.run_list = ['recipe[build-essential]', 'recipe[openssl]', 'recipe[postgresql::server]', 'recipe[database::postgresql]']

   end
```

Also I used `precise32` box.
And while my VM starts after `vagrant up`, I get [very long traceback](http://pastebin.com/tfvDnYwi) with error message: `undefined method`ruby' for Config:Module`.

Does anybody encountered this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be a problem installing the "pg" gem:

```
================================================================================      
Error executing action `install` on resource 'chef_gem[pg]'                          
================================================================================      

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError                                                  
-----------------------------------                                                  
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.                                          

        /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb                                        
checking for pg_config... yes                                                        
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config                                          
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes                                                        
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes                                                  
..
..
checking for st.h... yes                                                              
creating extconf.h                                                                    
creating Makefile                                                                    

make                                                                                  
sh: 1: make: not found
```

I suggest reading the documentation of the [build-essentials](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential) cookbook. It suggests setting the "compiletime" attribute in order to support to ensure that the build tools are available to compile RubyGems extensions.

### Update 1

The following json settings worked for me:

```
chef.json = { 
  "postgresql" => {
    "password" => {
      "postgres" => "password"
    }
  },
  "database" => {
    "create" => ["encased_dev"]
  },
  "build_essential" => {
    "compiletime" => true
  }
}
```

Note:

- Attribute is "build_essential" and not "build-essential"

### Updated 2

I have since discovered that there is a [ruby recipe](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/blob/master/recipes/ruby.rb) that fixes this issue as well (by setting the build essential node attributes about). Either add it to your run-list or use the [database cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database)

- https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/recipes/postgresql.rb

Comment: I have it in my config, but not sure about syntax. Tried different forms - and every time ended up with same error.

Comment: @lxark Yeah odd one. I discovered using the "database" cookbook indirectly solves the issue.

Comment: Why `build_essential` must be with underbar, not a dash? On the [homepage of the cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential) they write it as `build-essential`

Comment: @GillBates This mismatch between cookbook name and attribute naming convention has now been fixed. See the following commit: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential/commit/31e82be572a701b765bf6dbed1987987f366848a